# "git checkout ." とは

Tags: git

質問
1. `git chekcout .`とは？
2. このような記号の入ったものをうまく検索する方法は？

`git checkout`は分かるのですが、一度作業でエラーを出した際に「`git checkout .`したら？」というご意見をいただいたのですが、`git checkout .`とはなんでしょうか？
検索したのですが.が認識されないのか、ほしい情報が見つけられず。

状況としましては、gitでmergeしようとした際にファイルの情報が合わないというようなエラーメッセージがでました。
`git status`でリポジトリの状況を見たら、関係ない箇所のファイルを動かしてしまっていたらしく（GUIで主にファイル操作していたため）、その際に上記アドバイスをいただきました。
結果解決したのですが、何を自分でしたのかよくわかりません。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### `git checkout .` とは？

`git checkout <path>` の形式のコマンドで、`<path>` にカレントディレクトリを示すドット `.` が与えられているコマンドです。カレントディレクトリ下のステージされていない変更を全て取り消す効果を持ちます。

> **git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​**
>   Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the <tree-ish> (most often a commit).
>
> ([`git checkout` のドキュメントより引用](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203))

### 検索方法は？

私がよくやるのは、記号の英語名で検索することです。今回の場合 "git checkout single dot" や "git checkout period" などで検索すると引っ掛かります。

Comment: `git checkout .`を行った際に、今回の当方のファイルを動かしてしまった例でいうと①本来ファイルがあった場所にファイルがない、②本来ファイルがなかった場所にファイルが存在する、という二点の変更があったことになります。しかしコマンド実行時に、①は復元（？）され、②はそのままでしたので、別途コマンドで消去して元通りになりました。つまり変更を取り消すといっても復元はできるけれど、消去などはおこなわれないのでしょうか？

Comment: 移動したファイルは既にgitの管理下にあったので、`git checkout`に応じて復元や消去がされます。一方でまだステージング前(gitの管理下では無い)ファイルについてはそのまま残り続けます。